# Print google spreadsheet in iframe

Tags: iframe, printing

I am trying to make students report card of my school using Google spreadsheet...and i almost got it done.
i have embedded the spreadsheet in an iframe with the menu bar hidden. However within iframe i can not print any selected area. The printing dialog box pops up. But it does not generate the print preview.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>IFrame print</title>
<style>
html, body, iframe {height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
border-style: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14SSAevO4I_Jqi94aUAe1S1tad55gFvnsTcA9UWYp288/edit?usp=sharing&rm=minimal"
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to use some JavaScript too..i couldnt make it work

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do that. You need to have the content in the body itself to get the print that you want. Try running a funtion in app script returning the information from spreadsheet concatenated with HTML tags and then getting that string in HTML element by running a hava script function. there you go!